# Angular + Nginx in Docker, shared volume issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I shared a volume between Angular app and Nginx to serve app's generated files. At 1st startup everything is fine: Angular build goes successfully and Nginx serves created files.

But when I update image to make new build the files in shared folder aren't overwritten with newly built and Nginx serves old build.

I have

```
- app-client:/var/www
```

in volumes section of "nginx" service and

```
- app-client:/app/dist
```

in volumes section of "app" service in my docker-compose.yml

Angular outputs built files in /app/dist directory.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: That is in fact a major challenge when trying to use named volumes to publish files from one container to another.  Can you `COPY` the files into the Nginx-based image (maybe using a multi-stage build; maybe without a dedicated Angular container), instead of using a volume?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out that shared volumes unavailable on build phase but can be used in startup .sh script. So I added rm & cp commands to cleanup volume dir and copy app files into it. And finally it worked.